# antonym of constraint

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm looking for a word that can be used right next to the word "constraint" **in different grammatical structures**, but means the opposite. It should mean "**provide options to**".

For example:

> A company both constrains and XXX its employees.
>
> A company puts both constraints and XXX on its employees
>
> A company both constrains and XXX the behaviour of its employees.

I could think of words like "enables", which *kind of* makes sense for:

> A company both constrains and enables the behaviour of its employees.

But *doesn't* make sense for:

> WRONG: A company puts both constraints and (en)abilities (?) on its employees.

**Is there a word that is an antonym of constraint and also allows for the same syntactical usage?**

Comment: But what do you mean by _constrains_ here?

Comment: Try 'liberates'. Of course, one can't 'put liberations on' anyone, but in the first and third examples it could work. Another idea is to say 'a company both restricts and unrestricts the behaviour of its employees'. There's a nice symmetry to that phrasing, although I'm not sure it's true. In my experience, companies both limit and restrict their employees, but that's digressing from the topic.

Comment: I just came up with the word "enabler". A company puts both constraints and enablers on its employees. The problem is, that the word does not exist yet in this way, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Programmer2134 _enabler_ does exist in dictionaries. Check if that means what you want. https://www.google.com/#q=define+enablers

Comment: I guess the problem is that "enabler" means too much that there is an actual concrete entity (the enabler) that enables someone to do something, whereas a constraint does not need to be a concrete entity, it could be something more abstract, such as, there is a time constraint on a task, without referring to any particular entity that is enforcing this constraint.

Comment: I see. But what examples can you give about the company "enabling" its employees? Use `@NVZ` in your comment to send me notification, or I won't know if you responded.

Comment: @NVZ. Ok. The company constrains the employees by for example requiring them to arrive at the company at 9 AM (thereby constraining their actions. they can no longer go to the beach at 9 AM), but it "enables" their behaviour by giving them the new option to for example retreive data from some database for which the company has a subscription (they now have the option to retreive data from that database, which they would not have if it weren't for the company). A database could be for example Thomson Reuters' financial database, or something.

Comment: Enablements could be used with constraints. But, I think Empower in @NVZ's answer is better, since the word enable has acquired a negative taint from its use in describing the aiding of someone doing something bad.

Answer (score 5):

***Empower*** -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/empower)

> *Empower* means "give power or authority to." When you educate children and believe in them, you empower those kids to go after their dreams.

*"A company both constrains and empowers its employees."*

Your other example sentences will need a bit of rephrasing to use this.

Comment: well how would you rephrase them though? that's my main problem.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Your question was a single-word request, not a request for proofreading or writing advice. So, I don't think it's our duty to rephrase sentences for you. ;)

Comment: no my question was specifically about a word that would fit the same syntactic structures as "constrains" does, and I think empower doesn't do that. That's why I asked.

Comment: To pair with constraints, you could use empowerments.

Answer (score 1):

***Liberate*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/liberate)

> *verb* 1.2 Release (someone) from a state or situation that limits freedom of thought or behavior.
>   ‘the use of computers can liberate students from the constraints of disabilities’

*"A company both constrains and liberates its employees."*

Your other example sentences will need a bit of rephrasing to use this.

Comment: well how would you rephrase them though? that's my main problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good words being offered here. The difficulty is, I think, using the word "puts" for whatever it is you are constrasting with "constraints". More natural is "grants" or "gives". So, I'd be inclined to move "puts" to after the word "both". Then one way to word your second example would be:

*A company both puts constraints upon and grants **freedoms** to its employees.*

> **Freedom** *count noun*
>
> - a political right
> - franchise, privilege
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freedom)

As that definition suggests, others words which could replace **freedoms** here might be **privileges** or **rights**.

Comment: I agree, it is trying to use _puts on_ in relation to both **constraints** and its antonym which has caused some of the difficulties. Plus one for a clear answer.